# How to import tasks into your own playbook in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use rlesmithjr.manage-lvm role in my own playbook.
When running it says I have errors win the role statement. I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong!

```
# Create a Logical Volume to be mounted at /u02
- name: Create OracleDB_u02 Logical Volume
  roles:
    - role: rlesmithjr.manage-lvm
      lvm_groups:
        - vgname: OracleDB_u02
          disks: /dev/sdb  #for multiple disks...../dev/sdb,/dev/sdc
          create: true  #defines if VG should exist or be removed....true or false
          lvnames:
            - lvname: OracleDB_u02
              size: 30g  #define size of lvol...100%FREE, 10g, 1024 (megabytes by default)
              create: true  #defines if lvol should exist or be removed...true or false
              filesystem: ext4  #defines filesystem to format lvol as
              mount: true  #defines if filesystem should be mounte
              mntp: /u02  #defines mountpoint for lvol
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your playbook like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: do some stuff
    debug:
      msg: "Just doing random stuff"
  - role: rlesmithjr.manage-lvm
  - name: do more stuff
    debug:
      msg: "Doing more stuff"
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: It did!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Great, if it work for you, please mark the answer as valid so it will help other.